# Batch (or some other file) to have scheduled in Task Scheduler for a popup that leads to a website

Tags: batch, batch-file, scheduled-tasks, popups

I am trying to create a batch file (or some other file) to show a pop up reminder with a yes/no option that I can get set up to run at a designated time in task scheduler. This will be planned to run on basic computers so the end users will not have any major scripting software to run.

I need to set up a reminder for staff to check in each morning. If they select yes, I want it to just close the pop up, but if they check no, I want it to open up the website for them to check in.

I currently have a batch file with the following:

```
@echo off
del msgbox.vbs
echo x=msgbox("Reminder to sign in on School Checkin." ,4, "School Checkin Reminder") >> msgbox.vbs
start msgbox.vbs
```

So I can get it set up to show up with the yes/no option, but I would like it set up to when they press no, that it would open up the check-in site.

It does not need to be a batch file, but something that can at least run in the background without showing the commands and that can run through task scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way.
You can use [Microsoft HTA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_Application) to make a simple dialog with a yes and no button on it.  Your IT might not allow HTA but most do.

This is also very little code to do in c# but you would need to compile and distribute it.

What did you want the `[Yes]` button to do?  I made it simply close the window.

I made it open the default browser window to `DuckDuckGo.com` .. I am sure that isn't what you will be doing.

I am not here for continual support to make it do EXACTLY what you want.  I am giving you a starting point if it doesn't do what you want already.  ***I am happy to answer questions but not author your solution*** if this isn't it.  Perhaps your additions can be used to update this answer.

**Pros:**

- Built in to windows
- Web based GUI
- Direct access to vbscript or javascript (jscript)

**Cons:**

- You will see a flash when it opens.
- Many more cons will show up in the comment section I am sure ;-)

**To use it,** save the text to a file called anything you like with a HTA extension.

Double click to run and pick "Microsoft (R) HTML Application Host"
To run from task scheduler (or a shortcut), It will be `MSHTA <path_to_hta_file>`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Reminder to sign in on School Checkin</title>
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9">
    <meta name="author" content="Jeremy England">
    <meta name="copyright" content="SimplyCoded">
    <meta name="last-modified" content="2015-11-10">
    <hta:application
        border="thin"
        contextmenu="no"
        innerborder="no"
        icon="Narrator.exe"
        maximizebutton="no"
        minimizebutton="no"
        selection="no"
        singleinstance="yes" />

    <!--HTML APP SCRIPT-->
    <script type="text/vbscript">
' ---------
' On load
' ---------
 Sub window_onload()
  document.body.scroll = "no"
  window.moveTo 0,2000
  resizeWindow()
  window.moveTo 200,100
 End Sub
' ---------
' On Call 
' ---------
Class getWindowSize
 Function width()
 width = document.body.offsetWidth+16
 End Function
 Function height()
 height = document.body.offsetHeight+39
 End Function
 Function scrollHeight()
 scrollHeight = document.getElementById("tpArea").scrollHeight
 End Function
End Class

Set current = New getWindowSize

Function resizeWindow()
 ratio = 0.62
 wdth = current.width
 hght = current.width*ratio
 
 Do while current.height-50 <= current.scrollHeight
 If current.height >= screen.height-200 Or current.width >= screen.width-200 Then
  Exit Do
 Else
  wdth = wdth + 5
  hght = hght + 5*ratio
  window.resizeTo wdth, hght
 End If
 Loop
 
 Do while current.height-50 >= current.scrollHeight
 If current.height <= 155 Or current.width <= 250 Then
  Exit Do
 Else
  wdth = wdth - 5
  hght = hght - 5*ratio
  window.resizeTo wdth, hght
 End If
 Loop
End Function

' ---------
' On click
' ---------
 Function yesBtn()
   Window.Close()
 End Function

 Function noBtn()
  Set wsh=CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  wsh.Run "http://duckduckgo.com"
  Window.Close()  
 End Function
    </script>


    <!--HTML APP STYLE-->
    <style>
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 10pt;
        }

        #tpArea {
            margin: 10px;
            padding-bottom: 60px;
        }

        #btArea {
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0px;
            right: 0px;
            background-color: #ecf0f1;
            width: 100%;
            height: 50px;
            text-align: right;
        }

        button {
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 10pt;
            position: relative;
            top: 12.5px;
            right: 10px;
            width: 85px;
            height: 25px;
            margin-left: 5px;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 30px;
            background-color: #ffffff;
        }

            button:hover {
                color: #ecf0f1;
            }
    </style>
</head>


<!--HTML APP CONTENT-->
<body>
    <div id="tpArea">
        School Checkin Reminder
    </div>

    <div id="btArea">
        <button id="Ybtn" onclick="yesBtn()">Yes</button>
        <button id="Nbtn" onclick="noBtn()">No</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Original Unmodified HTA came from [here](https://gist.github.com/simply-coded/f49161aa40cae8a5ac10dad03bc8b331#file-msgbox-hta)

Answer (score 0):

Using your script,

1. Add [user input and and choice](https://ss64.com/nt/choice.html) (see also [Woude](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/choice.php)).
2. Add the command to start the default browser, e.g., `start <URL>`.

Answer (score 0):

Note that your prompt is not worded correctly: "Reminder to sign in on School Checkin" is not a yes/no question. Try "Did you sign in on School Checkin?"

So here is a "pure vbscript" option. Combines your existing snippet with a shell-object snippet from the HTA answer (the `Function noBtn()`). Wraps the "run command" in a test of the return value of the message box (`vbNo` is a vbscript defined constant).

```
dim wsh, x
x = msgbox("Did you sign in on School Checkin?" , 4, "School Checkin Reminder")
if x = vbNo then
    Set wsh = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    wsh.Run "http://duckduckgo.com", 1, false
end if
```

I tested it by running `wscript test.vbs` in a batch file. Presumably you can use this in a scheduler and avoid a batch file altogether, but you can echo this in the manner of your question example as it is compact.